# Drop Schema from Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to execute a few postgres commands from a bash file.

I am trying to drop a schema by writing the following line

```
DROP SCHEMA "xxx" IF EXISTS
```

I have two issues here

1. I am not sure how to specify the db from which the schema should be deleted
2. I am getting the following error message  -- "DROP: command not found"

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 10):

You cannot execute SQL statements directly from a bash script. Use `psql` to send the command to the database server. If you have a single (or a few) SQL statements to execute you can do it like this

```
psql -d YOUR_DB_NAME -c "YOUR_SQL_STATEMENT"
```

Make sure that your SQL statement does not include quotes or escape them appropriately. If you have many SQL statements in a file you can execute all of them like this

```
psql -d YOUR_DB_NAME -f FILENAME
```

In the above YOUR_DB_NAME should be replaced with your database name, YOUR_SQL_STATEMENT with the SQL statement you want to execute and FILENAME is the name of the file with SQL statements to be executed.

If you need to specify extra parameters like username, check the command's usage message displayed with `psql -?`.

Also, note that your syntax for `DROP SCHEMA` is incorrect. It should be

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS schema_name;
```

See also [this documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-dropschema.html).

Comment: Hi,
Thankyou for the reply.I tried the below lines of code in a test.sh file

pg_dump $dbname > testdb.backup
pg_dump $dbname -s -N 'public' >schema_backup.out

#Drop the user defined schema's
psql -d $dbname -c "DROP_SCHEMA aaa IF EXISTS;"
psql -d $dbname -c "DROP_SCHEMA bbb IF EXISTS;"

#restore the schema to restore the appropriate permissions
cat schema_backup.out | psql testdb

I am still getting the following error -- ERROR:  schema "aaa" already exists

Comment: Can you please help me how to fix this issue

Comment: "DROP: command not found" is gone and it looks your SQL actually makes it to the db server. However, your SQL is wrong. See this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-dropschema.html

Comment: It worked :-) Finally .......... after a day of struggle. 
Thanku for the help

Comment: @Trip Glad to see it helped. Added the description of the last issue to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

sure Adam Zalcman

Here is the final solution

dbname="xxxx"

## Make a copy of the full db

pg_dump $dbname > mydb.backup

## backup the schema's that we want to

pg_dump $dbname -s -N 'public' >test.out

## Drop the user defined schema's

psql -d $dbname -c "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS aaa CASCADE"
psql -d $dbname -c "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS bbb CASCADE"

## restore the schema to restore the appropriate permissions

cat test.out | psql $dbname

And it worked :-)